# Trouble in using jquery hide() function?

Tags: jquery, css, struts2

In the code given below, I am displaying images which opens in `prettyphoto` viewer after clicking on it.

```
  <s:iterator value="allPhotos">
    <a href="#inline-<s:property value="pictureid"/>" rel="prettyPhoto" >
      <img src="<s:property value="photourl"/>" alt="">
    </a>
    <div id="inline-<s:property value="pictureid"/>" id="hiddenimgbox">
      <img src="<s:property value="photourl"/>" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"><s:property value ="title" /></div>
    </div>

  </s:iterator>
```

The problem here I am facing is I am not able to hide the following div tag which should open in viewer only.

```
  <div id="inline-<s:property value="pictureid"/>" id="hiddenimgbox">
    <img src="<s:property value="photourl"/>" alt="">
    <div class="overlay"><s:property value ="title" /></div>
  </div>
```

Although I have the following script present in head of the document for hiding the `div`

```
  <script>
    $("#hiddenimgbox").hide();
  </script>
```

Please correct me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "element" is inside an `<s:iterator>` tag, so will in reality be multiple elements. However, in HTML pages IDs have to be **unique** - only one element should have a particular ID.

When you call `$('#hiddenimgbox')` it will only retrieve **one** of those elements, not all of them. Either make the IDs unique by adding a dynamic part to it, or use a class instead.

In addition, if you want the elements to default to being hidden, do it in the HTML, don't use JavaScript. It's unnecessary and will potentially result in the user seeing the page resize immediately upon loading.

There's also one more problem that I've just noticed: you're setting **two** `id` attributes when declaring the element:

```
<div id="inline-<s:property value="pictureid"/>" id="hiddenimgbox">
```

The second will likely just be ignored, so you'll never have any elements with an `id` equal to `hiddenimgbox`. In this case, I'd definitely suggest you switch `hiddenimgbox` to being a class on each element:

```
<div id="inline-<s:property value="pictureid"/>" class="hiddenimgbox" style="display:none">
```

Then, rather than using `$('#hiddenimgbox')` use `$('.hiddenimgbox')` instead when necessary.

Comment: @bril As I said, use HTML (in particular the `style` attribute) to hide the elements by default when the page loads, rather than using JavaScript. You shouldn't need any code, just take a look at the very last part of my answer.

Comment: thanks @anthony problem solved. And Thanks a lot for code review I am following that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the DOM to be loaded before you can access the elements on your page, use:

```
<script>
/* Wait until the DOM is ready */
$(function(){
    $("#hiddenimgbox").hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the id attribute twice. So browser will accept only the first one. Change it like this and try .

```
<div id="inline-<s:property value="pictureid"/> hiddenimgbox">
```